# Keras - Text preprocessing

Tags: text, tokenize, keras

## The goal:

### To generate text from an authors style.

Input: an authors work to train on, a seed for a prediction

Output: generated text from that seed

---

#### Question about the embedding layer in keras:

I have raw text, a flat text file containing a few thousand lines of text. I want to input this into an embedding layer to keras to vectorize the data. Here is what I have as text:

```
--SNIP
The Wild  West\n Ha ha, ride\n All you see is the sun reflectin\' off of the
--SNIP

and I call it input_text:

num_words = 2000#get 2000 words
tok = Tokenizer(num_words)#tokenize the words
tok.fit_on_texts(input_text)#takes in list of text to train on
#put all words from text into a words array
#this is essentially enumerating them
words = []
for iter in range(num_words):
    words += [key for key,value in tok.word_index.items() if value==iter+1]

#words[:10]
#Class for vectorizing texts, or/and turning texts into sequences 
#(=list of word indexes, where the word of rank i in the dataset (starting at 1) has index i).
X_train = tok.texts_to_sequences(input_text)#turns text to sequence, stating which word comes in what place
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=100)#pad sequence, essentially padding it with 0's at the end
y_train = words
```

#### The problem:

It seems that my code will take in the sequence, then when I apply padding it only gives the first 100 of the sequence. How should I break it apart?

Should I take the entire sequence and go through the first 100 words (X), and give the next one (Y) and do some skips along the way?

I want the output to be the probability of the next word coming up. So I have a softmax layer at the end. Essentially I want to generate text from a seed. Is this the correct way of going about doing this? or is it just better

Answer (score 0):

i think you will not find a better answer anywhere than on this page [here](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/), by the way code is also available on github, dive in or ask more questions.